# Getting a blocked IP from an EC2 security group without opening to 0.0.0.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firewall, aws-security-group, sniffing

I configured an external service to send traffic to my server on a specific port. The traffic arrives from an IP I do not know, and that is not mentioned in the service docs.

I would like to know that IP, so I can add it as an inbound rule to my EC2 security group.
One way to do that is opening the security group to 0.0.0.0 so any IP is allowed, then look at the traffic, and close the security group again, allowing only that IP.

Is there a smarter way of doing that, without opening to 0.0.0.0 even for a brief moment? For example if I could get a statistics about which IP's are getting blocked and on which port, I could deduce the IP from that.

Comment: This external service is something you expect? Or is it malicious traffic?

Comment: @Marcin I expect this traffic on this port, I just don't know what is going to be it's IP in advance. will edit the question to clarify

Comment: I think VPC FlowLogs could get IP info. You could setup flowlog for the ENI of yoru instance and have a look at the resulting logs.

Comment: Do you control this external service? If yes, how does it access the Internet? If it's using some form of dynamically-assigned IP, then you might not be able to use security groups to control access (because the IP might change).

Comment: @Parsifal This is a service out of my control, for example thing of it as forwarding traffic from a firewall to a server, or forwarding any data from a 3rd party SaaS